# Snowflake SQL - how to extract words from a string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string in a column like this.

I have 2 pets. One is "CAT" and "DOG".

I wanted to extract my output as **"CAT" and "DOG"**. Which is the beginning of double quotes to end of double quotes. How can I achieve this using snowflake SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
select regexp_substr('I have 2 pets. One is "CAT" and "DOG".', '".*"');
```

Output:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('I HAVE 2 PETS. ONE IS "CAT" AND "DOG".', '".*"')
"CAT" and "DOG"
```